# Prevent ProgressDialog from being dismissed when I click the search button (Android)

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

In a long-running operation, I'm showing a popup dialog (created from `ProgressDialog` to prevent other operations from happening).

I have made it non-cancellable with `setCancelable(false)`, so I can't close it using the back button, but surprisingly, the Search hardware button dismisses the dialog!

More exactly, the global search application is displayed, and when I come back to my app, the dialog has been dismissed.

Any idea how to prevent the dialog from being dismissed?

Comment: What about overriding the search button function? @Override public boolean onSearchRequested() { return true; }

Comment: Surprisingly, this does not work (at least testing it on 2.3).  Doesn't work if you return false either.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This works (notice I put it on the dialog builder):

```
.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            return true; // Pretend we processed it
        }
        return false; // Any other keys are still processed as normal
    }
})
```

Maybe it's even possible to grab the positive and negative button presses, and *only* handle these, return true for any other keys. Would be curious if you can figure that out...

PS: I read somewhere there are more "holes" in the dialog, i.e you can get rid of it without hitting any buttons on it. This was apparently one. Does anybody know of any others?

Comment: I get compiler errors when I run this, however removing `@Override` and changing onKey's declaration to `public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2)` worked for me - Thanks!

Comment: @MohamedHafez maybe change your compiler/IDE to check against Java 1.6 instead of 1.5?

Comment: @QQQuestions any idea why the getRepeatCount() == 0 has to be there?

Answer (score 37):

```
setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

`mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your dialogs via the Activity's [onCreateDialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Activity.html) event, as that is the point where they are managed by the Activity and they will be restored when the activity resumes.

Callback for creating dialogs that are managed (saved and restored) for you by the activity. If you use `showDialog(int)`, the activity will call through to this method the first time, and hang onto it thereafter. Any dialog that is created by this method will automatically be saved and restored for you, including whether it is showing. If you would like the activity to manage the saving and restoring dialogs for you, you should override this method and handle any ids that are passed to showDialog(int). If you would like an opportunity to prepare your dialog before it is shown, override `onPrepareDialog(int, Dialog)`.

Example usage:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
// ........ //
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
@Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {

  case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
   return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
     mDay);
  }
  return null;
 }

    public void launchSetDate() {
  showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
 }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, and the dialog was still dismissed when I press the search button.

Comment: And when you came back to the application?

Comment: the progress dialog is no more there :(

Answer (score 0):

simply use this code

> progressDialog.setMessage("please wait...");
> progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
> progressDialog.show();